# How to remove items from the model collection Using C#

Tags: c#

I have model collection in C#.

```
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters
```

This has 16 parameters list, as shown in the `Image_1`, I need to remove 3 items in the the parameters collection. How I can do this? I am not getting an idea how I can approach on this using C#.

Parameters which I need to remove from:

```
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters[2]
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters[5]
```

and

```
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters[8] items.
```

> **NOTE: It's not a duplicate question, Please help me.**

Image_1:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code vs just screenshots.  It would be helpful to have your model structure.  You mention you're trying to remove these in JQuery.  Are you serializing them to a JSON object?  You should be able to simply searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.RemoveAt(Index)

Comment: If you cant describe your structures and problem in code, then you probably don't have a programming question. pictures should not be needed 99.9 percent of times

Comment: Hi , I am sorry Its basically C# question, its not a JQuery question. I have a model collection where I need to remove 3 items from the collec tion, could you please help me

Comment: does your collection support remove at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your collection is, but if it implements RemoveAt you can do something like this:

```
for(int i = searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i == 2 || i ==5 || i == 8)
    {
        searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.RemoveAt(i);
    }            
}
```

or

```
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.RemoveAt(8);
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.RemoveAt(5);
searchesAndViews.SearchParameters[0].Parameters.RemoveAt(2);
```

The important thing is to do it in reverse order.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin for your honest response.